# Ubuntu does not start / Firmware Bug

Tags: boot, networking, 18.04, bios

After I have installed latest updates, my system does not boot. When I turn on my laptop purple screen apears and then nothing happens. When I enter advanced options for Ubuntu I have 2 system versions:

1. Version 5.0.0-23-generic: after running this, it shows white inscriptions on black background
2. Version 4.18.0-25-generic: after running this, system boot but I do not have internet.

Regarding first option (5.0.0-23-generic) it is written:

```
[0.039249] [Firwmware Bug]" TSC_Deadline disabled due to Errata; please ipdate microcode to version: 0x22 (or later)
[0.122879] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ae000000000
API 0 microcode 12
[4.458841] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000e
[4.496609] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[4.496642] CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.0.0-23-generic #24~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[4.496669] Hardware name: LENOVO 20238/INVALID, BIOS 79CN44WW(V3.03) 12/07/2013
[4.496693] Call Trace:
[4.496709] dump_stack+0x63/0x85
[4.496725] panic+0xfe/0x2a4
[4.496740] mount_block_root+0x1f4/0x2db
[4.496756] ? set_debug_rodata+0x139/0x18e
[4.496802] kernel_init_freeable+0x24a/0x272
[4.496820] ? reset_init+0xb0/0xb0
[4.496834] kernel_init+0xe/0x110
[4.496858] ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[4.496882] Kernel Offset: 0x4000000 from 0xffffffff8100000000 (relocation range: 0xffffff80000000-0xffffffbffffff)
[4.496917] --- [ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ] ---
```

I have never had such problem before. What should I do? Is it problem with BIOS?
I have laptop Lenovo G510, Ubuntu version 18.04.3 LTS, Gnome 3.28.2, BIOS 79CN44WW(V3.03)

My idea was to enter old version of Ubuntu from advanced options and install intel-microcode from solution, that I have found here, on this forum:

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

Unfortunately, I can not handle problem with internet (no WIFI, cable connection does not work too)

Comment: Does the recovery mode of `5.0.0-23` work? If so, then you might install the `intel-microcode` from there. As for whether this will help or not I don't know.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. above text shows when I enter into recovery 5.0.0-23.